# spring boot application on elastic beanstalk - health check fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my fat jar on elastic beanstalk ok, it is listening on port 5000 and is succesfully connecting to an RDS mysql instance on port 3306.

However, when I try to hit my API I get a 503 backend server overloaded etc error. I looked it up and it seems the cause is that the health check is failing

locally I can check system health with localhost:5000/health provided by spring boot actuator, but when I set /health as the endpoint for the load balancer to health check it fails. Since I don't have any 'healthy instances' running as they fail the health check the server is unavailable to REST requests.

Anyone know how to get the load balancer to succesfully ping the app for a health check ?

Comment: What type of load balancer?

Comment: What is /health? Is this a directory or an HTML page? If it is a directory you need to specify the actual full path to the page.

Comment: /health is a HTTP endpoint provided by the spring boot actuator package. It returns 200 ok and JSON {"status":up} if server is up

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your spring boot configuration, by default:

> the health endpoint is mapped to `/actuator/health`

[Part V. Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready features - Endpoinds](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints)

So your configuration on the load balancer should be something like this.

- HTTP code: 200
- Path: /actuator/health

And if by any chance you already set the property `server.servlet.context-path`, then you have to prefix that to the path.

The response code for different states of your app are:

- DOWN: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE (503)
- OUT_OF_SERVICE: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE (503)
- UP: No mapping by default, so http status is 200
- UNKNOWN: No mapping by default, so http status is 200

You can read the details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_writing_custom_healthindicators).